# Countifs function returns 0 in certain rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I've recently started using Google Sheets for my new job and I need help with a little problem.

I created a function to compare a whole column of dates from a sheet with dates from another column on another sheet to filter the given count.

The code is as follows:

```
COUNTIFS('raw data'!$D$2:$D$952;">="&('2nd table'!$C$3:$C$52);'raw data'!$D$2:$D$952;">=01.08.2021";'raw data'!$D$2:$D$952;"<=31.08.2021")
```

raw data contains dates in column D. I've used 952 because that is the maximum range I can get. I've yet to solve how to implement this via named ranges.

2nd table contains the dates our employees started working at the company. I wanted to filter out the data that exists before their time at our company within raw data column D.

The function does return the correct value sometimes and sometimes it just returns 0.

If I boil down the function to just contain this:

```
=COUNTIFS('raw data'!$D$2:$D$952;">="&('2nd table'!$C$3:$C$52))
```

I get different values each time. I suspect that I cannot use the function in this way because the 2nd table got a different amount of rows to compare from.

How can I work around this issue if that's the problem and why does the function even work sometimes?

Comment: Hey player, 

I'm afraid I can't because those sheets contain details of my employees that fall into the privacy laws of my country. I will follow up with a sheet that shows what I am trying to do without any personal information in it. I'll upload it in a few hours!

Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: By sharing spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). [Tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) are preferred. You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about that issue. I'll be careful in the future and hope to not get doxxed now..